# Speed up iteration through an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, minecraft

I've been trying to get this block of code to run faster/more efficiently but I seem to be having a lot of trouble with it.

```
    resp = {}
    ipIter = iter(ipList)

    #Check status of MineCraft Server
    def checkStatus(ip):
        try:
            server = JavaServer.lookup(ip)
            status = server.status()
            q = server.query()
            resp['Online'] = True
            resp['address'] = ip
            resp['players_online'] = q.players.names
            resp['players_max'] = q.players.max
            resp['version'] = status.version.name
            resp['plugins'] = q.software.plugins
            #with args.output as ofile:
            print(json.dumps(resp))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Server {ip} is offline with error {str(e)}")

    for x in range(len(ipList)):
        checkStatus(next(ipIter))
```

I've toyed with the idea of using multi-threading/multi-processing to help it run faster, but I'm unsure if that's the best way to do it. I've already tried looking at a bunch of different ways for it to run faster but nothing has worked so far.

Is there anything I can be doing better?

To clarify, a script I wrote that hooks into an api can run through a list of ~428 IPs in about 15 minutes. The one I'm currently working on does roughly 1 IP every 10 seconds. It'd take over an hour to do all ~428 IPs.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by wrapping the list in iter and using next? That's not faster than an ordinary for loop? Though note, your perf problems are certainly in the checkStatus function

Comment: unrelated, but are you iterating this way? `for x in range(len(ipList)): checkStatus(next(ipIter))`? Just iterate over the list directly, `for ip in ipList: checkStatus(ip)`

Comment: Anyway, the problem here is almost certainly the network I/O, so multithreading could potentially speed it up.

Comment: Hah, we said the same thing :) good work.

Comment: Although note, I'm pretty sure you don't want to be re-using the global dictionary....

Comment: I was using an ordinary for loop before, but I thought it was slower than just using iter instead. What would you recommend instead of re-using the global dictionary?

Comment: @AustynHoward just create a new dictionary inside the function. Anyway, I don't know why you thought it was faster doing what you are doing above, it is essentially the same thing that happens when you use `for item in mylist: ...`, except that is implemented in C as part of the Python runtime. The point is, it isn't the *loop* that is the problem. Just do `for x in range(1_000_000): pass` and you'll see that looping over something with even a million elements seems practically instantaneous.

Answer (score 2):

Python comes with a thread-based worker [pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) implementation, `ThreadPool`:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def checkStatus(ip):
    # exceptions will be logged to stderr - so, I'd skip printing
    # make sure this call is thread-safe
    server = JavaServer.lookup(ip)
    status = server.status()
    q = server.query()
    return {
        # 'Online': True,  # perhaps not very helpful as only True is returned
        'address': ip,
        'players_online': q.players.names,
        'players_max': q.players.max,
        'version': status.version.name,
        'plugins': q.software.plugins
    }

# optionally, pass number of threads; using number of cores by default
tp = ThreadPool()
data = tp.map(checkStatus, ipList)
```

Comment: Given that they have different IPs, I guess the servers won't mind (or even notice) if they're all accessed at the same time. Is `Threadpool(len(ipList))` the best way then?

Comment: @KellyBundy My experience with external API (extremely scalable endpoint, but with a more CPU demanding postprocessing) was best with 20..30 threads. I'd try several numbers to figure out the best one, as it might depend on too many local factors (CPU, network bandwidth, disk IO etc)

Comment: Now I'm getting a BlockingIOError, I've looked into it and it seems to be something to do with Blocking Connections.

Comment: @AustynHoward it is really hard to what's the issue from here. Providing error message/logs might help

Comment: @Marat This is the error I'm getting now:  UDP port 53 answered The DNS operation timed out.